# Random numbers being printed instead of my var

Tags: c

I have a exercise and then I need to read as many numbers as the user wants, show the higher one and how many times it was read. I tried to build the code and in my mind it should work, but when it comes to show the number and etc it shows some "random numbers" instead of my var called "max".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int aux1, j, i,k, max = -99999,cont;

    printf("How many numbers will be read: \t");
    scanf("%d", &aux1);

    int vet[aux1];

    for(k=0;k<aux1;k++){
        printf("Digit a number: \t");
        scanf("%d",&vet[k]);
    }

    for(i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++){
        if(vet[i] > max) max=vet[i];
    }

    cont=1;
    j=0;

    while(j<=aux1){
        if(max==vet[j]){
            cont++;
        }
        j++;
    }
    printf(" The higher number is %d and it was read %d times \n", max, cont);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

If i input on screen that i want to read 3 numbers as a example, then input 1, 2 and 3 it gives me that the higher number is "1954048954" and was read 1 times, when it should give me "3 is the higher number and it was read 1 time"

Comment: Your line "for(i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++)" should probably be "for(i = 0 ; i<aux1 ; i++)"

Comment: Learn how to debug small programs: use a debugger.

Comment: You should always check the return value of `scanf`

Comment: Note that you don't actually have to read all the numbers in memory at once. You can keep track of the max and how many times it's been read as you read them.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. I'll try to change it later, thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're reading past the end of your array:

```
for(i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++){
   if(vet[i] > max) max=vet[i];
}
```

If you enter in 3 for `aux1`, then `vet` is an array of 3 numbers, but here you loop through 10 array elements.  This reads past the end of the array, invoking [undefined beahvior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Fix the loop to be within the size of the array:

```
for(i = 0 ; i<aux1 ; i++){
   if(vet[i] > max) max=vet[i];
}
```

You have a similar issue here when counting the max element:

```
while(j<=aux1){
    if(max==vet[j]){
        cont++;
    }
    j++;
}
```

You have an off-by-one error here, your loop condition should instead be:

```
while(j<aux1){
```

Comment: @Erik glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.